# Text alignment not working in 'select' element with Safari

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

I'm trying to align the text in the select element by setting:

```
text-align:right;
direction:rtl;
```

Somehow it's working with all browsers including FF, IE, Chrome and Safari on iPad2. With safari on iPhone and PC it's aligned to the left and cannot be changed.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="field">
    <select>
        <option value="6" selected="selected">אישה מחפשת גבר</option>
        <option value="9">גבר מחפש אישה</option>
        <option value="10">אישה מחפשת אישה</option>
        <option value="5">גבר מחפש גבר</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.field select {
    text-align:right;
    direction:rtl;
}
```

I Googled it a bit and saw others that had this issue and fix nowhere to be found. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

it is working correctly in safari 5.1.5 on PC

[image]

Comment: In your pic it's aligned to the left. I need right alignment.